# Upload a text document by ftp but the file is blank / empty

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

Following is the code snippet to copy txt file from a location to a ftp path:

```
WebRequest WRequest = WebRequest.Create(FtpPath + OriginalfileName);
WRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
WRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "FtpPassword");
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(OriginalFilePath);
byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
Stream RStream = WRequest.GetRequestStream();
RStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
RStream.Close();
```

But the copied file at ftp destination is always empty. Why?

Comment: Did you debug your code line by line ?

Comment: yes @SonerGönül  .. the original file size is 1kb... but the buffer here has a size of 478bytes only.. and so the destination file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not populating the buffer with the contents of the file.  You're just setting the length in the following line of code:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
```

And you're not filling it with the contents of the file anywhere else, either, so you're just sending empty data to the FTP server.  The bytes may have a certain length, but it's all empty bytes.

Comment: So I will have to convert the filestream to bytes and that should be there in the Buffer .. right?

Comment: you need to write the bytes in a While loop.. I will post an example that should work the same way for example if you were to copy bytes

Comment: using (FileStream FStream = File.OpenRead(LWFilePath))
                using(Stream RStream = WRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[FStream.Length];
                    BinaryReader BReader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(FStream);
                    buffer = BReader.ReadBytes((int)FStream.Length);                    
                    RStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    RStream.Close();
                }

Comment: There are code samples here for reading from a file.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread(VS.71).aspx  IN your case, choose the "read from a binary file" since you want to get they bytes, and not a string.

Answer (score 2):

As a simple solution you can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx) class

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
client.UploadFile(uriString,fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the same type of logic when writing bytes except in my case I passed in an initial size

```
public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is Stream.CopyTo for doing the same thing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx

Comment: yes Gonzalo I was just giving the OP an example explaining why his stream was not copying over any content..

Comment: There is also a good example of how to use FtpWebRequest Class if you want to review in your spare time - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for file upload using IFormFile in asp.net core 2.1

```
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("*******/site/wwwroot/wwwroot/images/" + TempFileName);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.Method = "STOR";
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***", "****");

                // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
                byte[] fileContents = null;

                if (vehicle.FileUpload.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        await vehicle.FileUpload.CopyToAsync(ms);
                        var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                        fileContents = fileBytes;
                    }
                }
                request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                }
```

Here is the view model for file

```
public class VehicleSeriesViewModel
    {
        public Guid VehicleBadgeId { get; set; }
        public Guid VehicleSeriesId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public IFormFile FileUpload { get; set; }
        public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
    }
```